# How to make a div both do scale animation on hover and translateY animation at the same time

Tags: html, css

I have this code: https://codepen.io/sabeser/pen/BaOeBPW

```css
:root {
  --scale--ratio: 1;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
}

.circle {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 20em;
  -webkit-animation: floataround 1.1s infinite alternate;
  animation: floataround 1.1s infinite alternate;
  transform: scale(var(--scale--ratio)) translate(0%, 0%);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transition: transform .9s;
  margin: 1em;
}

@keyframes floataround {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-8px);
  }
}

.circle:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: green;
  --scale--ratio: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div class='circle'>

  </div>

  <div class='circle'>

  </div>
</div>
```

It shows two circles that move up and down:

[image]

However each circle is supposed to scale on hover. The scaling is only achieved if I remove code that is responsible for movement:

```
  -webkit-animation: floataround 1.1s infinite  alternate;
  animation: floataround 1.1s infinite  alternate;
```

How do I achieve it?

Comment: Just a small heads up: it's a really bad idea to make interactive widgets move. If something is meant to react to a cursor hovering over it or clicking, you should not move the same thing while it's being hovered over. That makes for a really frustrating UX.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Hm, so a hover event should also pause a moving animation? Is that possible to achieve in CSS?

Comment: I am not sure how you would implement it in detail (haven't tried). It's just a consideration to keep in mind when building this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep the `scale()` function in your `@keyframes`, otherwise you are fully overriding `transform` property:

```css
@keyframes floataround {
  0% {
    transform: scale(var(--scale--ratio)) translateY(0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(var(--scale--ratio)) translateY(-8px);
  }
}
```

If you want to smoothly animate the scaling effect on hover, then you have to use the individual transform properties [`scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scale) and [`translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/translate), like so:

```css
:root {
  --scale--ratio: 1;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
}

.circle {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 1em;
  border-radius: 20em;
  /* set default scale */
  scale: var(--scale--ratio);
  /* enable scale animation */
  transition: scale 1.1s;
  -webkit-animation: floataround 1.1s infinite alternate;
  animation: floataround 1.1s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes floataround {
  0% {
    translate: 0;
  }
  100% {
    translate: 0 -8px;
  }
}

.circle:hover {
  /* update scale */
  --scale--ratio: 1.2;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div class='circle'></div>
  <div class='circle'></div>
</div>
```

Note: Individual transform properties are fairly new and may not be supported on all devices. However, according to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=scale), they are supported by nearly 90% of user devices these days.

Comment: I tried to do this: https://codepen.io/sabeser/pen/OJoYLYm, but the result is the same

Comment: The scale is happening, but the transition is instant. But this does solve the initial problem.

Comment: @AabhushanGautam When I go to the code pen, on hover only the color is changed, not the size of a circle. And the question was about how to keep both animations the way they are - including the transition duration

Comment: @parsecer I don't entirely understand your intended behavior because the two codepens do not show the same behavior. But are you saying you want the scaling to smoothly animate on hover, as well?

Comment: I appended an explanation for smoothly animating scaling to my answer.

Comment: @DennisKats The intended behavior is: 1. each circle is moving up and down 2. each circle gets bigger while mouse hovers over it

Comment: The CodePen you commented removed the transform property from the `.circle` styles, hence why it’s not working as expected. Check out the CodePen I added to my answer.

Comment: @DennisKats In your code pen the circles neither move nor get scaled on hover... ; (

Comment: I tested the CodePen on multiple devices and modern browsers with default settings, and it seems to work as intended. What device and browser version are you using? Are you sure you don't have any other CSS overriding the styles of the circles?

Comment: If you all would use Stack Snippets instead of CodePen, all of this could be done on this site instead of bouncing between sites...

Comment: Fair enough, I only used it because the OP did and I forked their code. But I'll update  my answer to use Stack Snippets

Comment: @DennisKats It's interesting. I've been using Brave and the circles are motionless and scaless here. In firefox it works, on the other hand!

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue in Brave either, but consider filing a bug report with Brave's "Report a broken site" button